# Why code using local struct as parameter for STL function does not compile in g++?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, g++, c++11

I have such code which works well:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

char x[11]= "ABCDEFGHIJ";
char y[11];

struct F {
    char operator () (char c) const 
    { return c+1; }
};

int main()
{
    std::transform(x, x+10, y, F());
    y[10] = 0; std::cout <<y <<std::endl;
}
```

But if I change it to this style:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

char x[11]= "ABCDEFGHIJ";
char y[11];

int main()
{
    struct F {
        char operator () (char c) const 
        { return c+1; }
    };
    std::transform(x, x+10, y, F());
    y[10] = 0; std::cout <<y <<std::endl;
}
```

It will not compile, saying:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(char [11], char*, char [11], main()::F)’

What's wrong?

gcc version is 4.4, which does not recognize lambda expressions.

Comment: Are you compiling as C++03 or C++0x?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++-98/03 the second code is not valid, since F is a local type; in facts, at §14.3.1.2 it's stated that

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.
>
> [Example:

```
template <class T> class X { /* ... */ };
void f()
{
    struct S { /* ... */ };
    X<S> x3;         // error: local type used as template-argument
    X<S*> x4;        // error: pointer to local type used as template-argument
}
```

> —end example] [Note: a template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). ]

In C++-0x this limitation is removed; in the same section, the new standard draft (N3126) explicitly shows this in the example:

> [ Example:

```
template <class T> class X { };
template <class T> void f(T t) { }
struct { } unnamed_obj;

void f() {
    struct A { };
    enum { e1 };
    typedef struct { } B;
    B b;
    X<A> x1;             // OK
    X<A*> x2;            // OK
    X<B> x3;             // OK
    f(e1);               // OK
    f(unnamed_obj);      // OK
    f(b);                // OK
}
```

> — end example ] [ Note: a template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). — end note ]

Comment: We're in C++03 or C++0x, not C++98 anymore. Of course, the point is still valid, but quoting from an outdated Standard is meaningless.

Comment: @DeadMG: unfortunately I couldn't find a free draft of C++03, so I have to stick to C++98 for quotations `:(` ; still, I checked the unofficial list of changes and §14.3 is not included in the changes, so the quotation should be still valid for C++03.

Comment: I see ... do you know why such limitation came about?

Comment: There is no such thing as C++03. There is exactly one C++ Standard in existence at this time (C++98 if you like). C++0x which will actually be more like C++11 may become a standard soon but it isn't yet.

Comment: @Yttrill:  Yes, there is.  C++03 refers to ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E), which is the current C++ Standard (it replaced the C++98 Standard).

Comment: @Yttrill Hmm, I thought so too. But looking up, it seems that C++03 isn't actually a TC, but a completely new version of C++. This seems to be contradicted by GCC and Clang though, which only have -std=c++98 and say "The 1998 ISO C++ standard plus amendments. Same as -ansi for C++ code.". Weird!

Answer (score 4):

g++ 4.5.1 [compiles your code](http://ideone.com/z1GhE) (with `-std=c++0x` option).

Your second code sample is ill-formed in C++03<sup>1</sup> but valid in C++0x

`std::transform` is

```
template < class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperator >
  OutputIterator transform ( InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                             OutputIterator result, UnaryOperator op );
```

However g++ 4.4 [doesn't support local types as template arguments](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) (even with -`std=c++0x` option] so you get an error.

<sub>1 : A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter. (ISO C++03 §14.3.1.2)</sub>